# jquery add <picture> image on div

Tags: javascript, jquery

If in jquery do:

```
txt = '<img loading="lazy" src="photo.jpg">';

$('#my_div').append(txt);
```

works fine, print my image but y if use responsive picture source like

```js
txt = '<picture>';
txt += '<source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/100">';
txt += '<img loading="lazy" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50">';
txt += '</picture>';

$('#my_div').append(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my_div"></div>
```

not work with picture. jQuery can't append picture??

Comment: We can't really reproduce this to fully help you.  I advise you include a code snippet.

Comment: See the snippet I created from your code. Does it demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine. If you are testing it on your desktop or laptop (bigger screen) it wont show. It will show in smaller screens like mobile which are less than 500px.

In the below example, my_div shows image, but not my_div_2, because of screen size

```js
txt = '<picture>';
txt += '<source media="(max-width: 500px)" srcset="photo_small.jpg">';
txt += '<img loading="lazy" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">';
txt += '</picture>';

$('#my_div').append(txt);

txt = '<picture>';
txt += '<source media="(min-width: 500px)" srcset="photo_small.jpg">';
txt += '<img loading="lazy" src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_pink_flowers.jpg">';
txt += '</picture>';


$('#my_div_2').append(txt);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div"></div>

<div id="my_div_2"></div>
```